# are two consecutive numbers relatively prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing

I have a question.

I have been given this proof: "For any $n$ in the integers where $n>2$, show there are at least $2$ elements in $U(n)$ that satisfy $x^2=1$."

I have gone through and actually proved this, (that the numbers are $1$ and $n-1$) but i didn't' know how to prove that $n-1$ is **in fact** in the set $U(n)$. Is it because two consecutive numbers are always relatively prime?

Comment: What is $U(n)$?

Comment: @Sigur: $U(n)$ is the multiplicative group of integers mod $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: Yes, that is why, and Jason Bourne has just supplied a proof.

Comment: $-1$ is an integer.

Answer (score 25):

$n$ is coprime to $n-1$, for if $d$ divides $n$ and $d$ divides $n-1$, then $d$ divides $n-(n-1)=1$.

Comment: ah ! such a nice, neat, simple proof. thank you so much

Comment: Nice, and concise! (I'd say well-done, and concise, but nice rhymes with concise!) +1

Comment: $n$ is coprime to $n−2$, for if $d$ divides $n$ and $d$ divides $n−2$, then $d$ divides $n−(n−2)=2$ ?

Comment: Not coprime obviously but I suppose if d divides n and n-2 then d=2 thus n is even.