# Show that $5n+3$ and $7n+4$ are relatively prime for all $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $5n+3$ and $7n+4$ are relatively prime for all $n$.

Comment: Do you know how to use the [Euclidean algorithm](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/euclidean-algorithm/)? All of your previous questions are variants on it. You should learn how to use this basic technique.

Comment: I don't know why this question was downvoted. It's a valid, genuine question.

Comment: Calculate $(5n+3,7n+4)=(5n+3,2n+1)=(n+1,2n+1)=(n+1,1)=1$ via iterating the relations $(a,b)=(a,b-ma)=(a-mb,b)$ to reduce the coefficient of $n$ each step. Here $(a,b)$ stands for gcd. This is the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bezout's Lemma states that for if and only if $a$ and $b$ are comprime numbers then the following equation has integer solutions:

$$ax + by = 1$$

Now let $a=5n+3$ and $b=7n+4$. Now we get:

$$(5n+3)x + (7n+4)y = 1$$

Now apply the extended Euclidean Algorithm:

$$(7n+4) = (5n+3) + (2n+1)$$
$$(5n+3) = 2\times(2n+1) + (n+1)$$
$$(2n+1) = (n+1) + n$$
$$(n+1) = n + 1$$

We now just go back:

$$1 = (n+1) - n$$
$$1 = (n+1) - ((2n+1) - (n+1))$$
$$1 = 2(n+1) - (2n+1)$$
$$1 = 2((5n+3) - 2(2n+1)) - (2n+1)$$
$$1 = 2(5n+3) - 5(2n+1)$$
$$1 = 2(5n+3) - 5((7n+4) - (5n+3)$$
$$1 = 7(5n+3) - 5(7n+4)$$

We just obtained one solution $(x,y) = (7,5)$, but it's enough to prove that $7n+4$ and $5n+3$ are comprime numbers.

Comment: This is very thorough and understandable. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you really mean $7n+4+5n+3$ at the end? I think you mean the middle $+$ to be an '&' character, or just write "and."

Answer (score 18):

Hint:  $\gcd(5n+3,7n+4)=\gcd(35n+21,35n+20)$, why?

Once you can verify my question, all that remains is to show that [consecutive integers are coprime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296748).

Comment: Great Rustyn (+1)

Answer (score 9):

If $p$ is a prime divisor of $5n+3$ and $7n+4$ then $$5n+3 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$ and $$7n+4 \equiv 0 \pmod p.$$  At least one of these is not satisfied when $p \in \{5,7\}$.  Otherwise, $7$ and $5$ are invertible modulo $p$ and we can rearrange these equations as $$\frac{-4}{7} \equiv n \equiv \frac{-3}{5} \pmod p.$$  This implies $-20 \equiv -21 \pmod p$, giving a contradiction, since $p \geq 2$.

Answer (score 8):

Since $7(5n+3) - 5(7n+4)=1$ the greatest common divisor is $5n+3$ and $7n+4$ is $1$ (by Bezout's identity).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** 
$$7n+4=(5n+3)+2n+1$$
$$5n+3=2(2n+1)+1$$