# Prove that for $n>2$, $n$ cannot be a factor of $n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For the sake of contradiction, we assume $n$ is a factor of $n+1$. Then by definition of divisibility, $nk = n+1$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Case $1$: $k = 1$. Then $n = n+1$ which is a contradiction.
Case $2$: $k>1$.

I am stuck on how to approach a contradiction in Case $2$.

Comment: Hint:  show that if $n$ divides $n+1$ then it must divide $1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296747/are-two-consecutive-numbers-relatively-prime/296748#296748

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
$$nk=n+1 \Longrightarrow n(k-1)=1$$